# change cell background using ngHandsOnTable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm able to render table cells using ngHandsOnTable.
On clicking a submit button, I want to be able to change the background color of a particular cell. Problem with ngHandsOnTable wrapper is, I don't have a way to access to 'td' property. (using which I can modify it like this td.style.background = "yellow" for example)

I tried using a customRenderer and tried to save td object in two dimensional array. But, if I save td object reference, background property change does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have happened to solve the problem by using afterRender callback. If I use td.style.background in this call, cells are changing its background color.
Not sure if some default callbacks were overwriting the cell background to white previously.

In NgHandsontable, I got hold of hot instance using afterInit callback.

refer my comments here: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/3206

```
var afterRender= function (color) {
    var td = hotInstance.getCell(row, col);
    td.style.background = color;
}

var afterInit = function () {
    hotInstance = this;
}

$scope.adjSettings = {
    afterInit: afterInit,
    afterChange: onCellEdit,
    afterRender: afterRender
};
```